# CursorLoader in a Non Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I have small project where I read system metrics like Calls Logs, SMS Logs etc from content providers.

I have created **(Call/SMS)Logger** classes to read from content providers and save info in object of **(Call/SMS)Metrics** clases.

The **MainActivity** uses the info in the objects of **(Call/SMS)Metrics** classes and saves the data in my own database using a databaseOpenHelper class.

Now I intend to use CursorLoader to load datafrom contentproviders.

The examples I have seen suggest that MainActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks

**How can I use this in my project when actual query stuff is done on non activity classes?**

**Can I create I 1 loaderManger in Activity and use for every non Activity?**

Here is some sample code snippets:

From Main Activity I call the collection of data, I pass the context to the clssess so that they can use it in manager cursor

```
private void CollectSystemMetrics() {
    //passing the context in constructor so that it can be passed to 
    //the non activity classes which need it for quering
    SystemMetricsCollector collector = new SystemMetricsCollector(this);        
    _callMetrics = collector.CollectCallMetrics();
    _smsMetrics = collector.CollectSMSMetrics();

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(
            MyActivity.this,
            "Calls and SMS Data Collected",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

Method in SystemMetricsCollector to raed SMSData

```
public SMSMetrics CollectSMSMetrics() {
    SMSLogger smsLogger = new SMSLogger(_context);
    smsLogger.ReadSMSDataFromPhone();
    return smsLogger.GetSMSMetrics();
}
```

Variables in SMSLogger class.

```
Uri smsUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
String[] selectColumns = null;
String where = null;
String whereArgs[] = null;
String sortBy = null;
```

Methods in SMSLogger to read data using cursor

```
public void ReadSMSDataFromPhone() {
    int inCount = 0, outCountContacts = 0, outCountUnknown = 0;
    Cursor managedCursor;
    managedCursor = _context.getContentResolver().query(
            smsUri,selectColumns,where,whereArgs,sortBy);
    try {
        if (managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int idxAddress = managedCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address");
            int idxType = managedCursor.getColumnIndex("type");
            do {
                int valType = managedCursor.getInt(idxType);
                switch (valType) {
                    case 2://outgoing
                        String valAddress = 
                        managedCursor.getString(idxAddress);
                        if (isContact(valAddress)) outCountContacts++;
                        else outCountUnknown++;
                        break;
                    default://incoming
                        inCount++;
                        break;
                }
            } while (managedCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } finally {
        managedCursor.close();
    }//end finally
    _smsMetrics.set_receivedSMS(inCount);
    _smsMetrics.set_sentSMSContacts(outCountContacts);
    _smsMetrics.set_sentSMSUnknown(outCountUnknown);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I use this in my project when actual query stuff is done on non activity classes?

Either have the activity be the one to actually use the `Loaders`, or do not use `Loaders`. You are welcome to use a `ContentResolver` in an `AsyncTask` or `Thread` instead.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of AsyncTask in scenario of my application. I am already using content resolver in my code but the GUI (activity) becomes unresponsive from function call until all database operations are finished.

Comment: @KhurramMajeed: Put your existing `ReadSMSDataFromPhone()` logic in `doInBackground()` of the `AsyncTask`. Update the UI from `onPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on what your use case is but...

The point of the activity implementing LoaderCallbacks is just ease of use. You can declare your LoaderCallbacks wherever you want and just give it to the loaderManager:

```
LoaderCallbacks blah = new LoaderCallbacks() {
//Override methods here
}

getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, blah);
```

Note that `getLoaderManager()` is normally tied to a Fragment or Activity though.

Comment: I wan to use the CursorLoader Functionally in my non Activity classes e.g SMSLogger class