# Call LoaderManager from class which is not Activity

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

I'm working on to get contacts from phone, for this purpose I'm using `LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` I create a new class with `FetchContacts` name and implement `loaderManager`. Now I want when ever I create object of that class loaderManager automatically initialize.
**FetchContacts**

```
  public class FetchContacts implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
       private Context context;

     FetchContacts(Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this); // Error: Undefined method
     }  
     // Reset of code like override methods.
```

**MainActivity**

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           FetchContacts fetchContacts = new FetchContacts(this);
       }
     }
```

I know the reason of error because `FetchContacts` is not extend from Activity class. Is it necessary to extend it from Activity class or is there and other method to call it from MainActivity ?

Comment: You could pass the `LoaderManager` as an argument in the `FetchContacts` constructor, but I'm not really sure why you want to do it this way. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13433085

Comment: Because I want to get the contacts whenever I need it. If I'm not able to call `initLoader()` then this class is useless. Is there anyother way to do this. I'm new in android. Passing `loaderManager` is a good way ?

Comment: You don't need a `Loader` to get Contacts. `Loader`s are mainly for delivering content updates, changes, etc. to a UI component, like an `Activity`. You can always query the Contacts Provider yourself wherever you have access to a `Context`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12562151 To specifically answer your last question, no, using a `LoaderManager` like that is not really a good way to do this.

Comment: But I find something that `cursorLoader` is good `Note: All the examples in this lesson use a CursorLoader to retrieve data from the Contacts Provider. A CursorLoader runs its query on a thread that's separate from the UI thread. This ensures that the query doesn't slow down UI response times and cause a poor user experience` This is from android developer https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html#Permissions

Comment: Yeah, I figured that's where you got it from, when I went searching for that example. As I said, `Loader`s are for delivering results to an `Activity` or `Fragment`. If those are the only places you need the results, then there's no need for your separate class; just implement the necessary `Loader` setup in whichever `Activity`/`Fragment` you need. If by "I want to get the contacts whenever I need it", you mean you're trying to use that one `Loader` or its results somewhere else, you're gonna have a bad time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass `LoaderManager` as an Argument as @Mike said.

**FetchContacts**

```
  public class FetchContacts implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
       private Context context;

     FetchContacts(Context ctx, LoaderManager loaderManager){
        context = ctx;
        loaderManager.initLoader(0, null, this); 
     }  
     // Reset of code like override methods.
```

**MainActivity**

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           FetchContacts fetchContacts = new FetchContacts(this, getLoaderManager());
       }
     }
```

Comment: Note - this should be used with caution as the LoaderManager class holds a reference to the activity.  If you're not careful, this can lead to memory leaks.